# How to embed equation queries in elasticSearch

Tags: python-3.x, regex, parsing, elasticsearch, elk

I have my search engine build using embeddings from documents using ELK...I want to query using mathematical equations and their respective outcomes.

for example: My query is Give me water pH 8+-1
The outcome should be:every document with an pH value from 7 to 9

Exampe 2:Density 1080 would search Density 1080 +- 10% by meaning 1080 +- 108 or, pH 7 would search pH 7 +- 10% by meaning 7 +- 0.7

How can i do this?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, please look at how to ask good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Specifically, write in question what you have tried till now.

Comment: anyone any help??

Comment: @WiLL_K I tried this but not working.

 "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "(doc['price'].value + params.foo) > params.bar",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params" : {
                            "foo" : 50,
                            "bar" : 20
                        }